# javascript animation - chaotically moving points (like ping-pong bubbles)

Tags: javascript, css

Never was strong in drawing in JS or any other, that's why I have to ask community to help.

Does someone tried to make a Animation like "ping-pong bubbles", using Javascript/HTML/CSS?

i want to make some kind of simulation when people moving on the in-building map with simple algorithm:
1. Init Canvas
2. Draw red(for ex.) points
3. Move red points slowly between "walls"

Comment: This might be not exactly what you want / need, but I've had a lot of fun with this tutorial and it teaches you the basics for what you want to do
http://learnsome.co/blog/particles/

Comment: Cool. Looks like exactly that I need. I will try and let you know about result